# Ajax is bypassing JQuery validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, plugins, jquery-validate

I currently am using the Jquery validation on my form. However I am also using ajax to submit. When I click submit, without filling out the input the form goes through despite the fact I put validation. Please advise.

Here is my code:

Jquery validation code:

```
$(function() {
   $("#mytestform" ).validate({
           rules: {
                   aname: {
                           required: true,
                           minlength: 4,
                           maxlength: 20
                   },
                   req: {
                           required: true,
                           minlength: 4                        
                                              },
                        email: {
                               required: true,
                               email: true
                       },                      
           },

           messages: {
                       email: "Enter a valid email address.",
             },
   });
});

</script>


Here is my ajax code:
<script language="Javascript">
   //var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&email=' + email + '&phone=' + phone;  
    //alert (dataString);return false;  
    $("#mytestform").submit(function(event) {
        // Assign handlers immediately after making the request,// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
    event.preventDefault();
    var jqxhr = $.post("testme.php", $("#mytestform").serialize());
    jqxhr.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
        //alert(textStatus + " second success " + data); 
        $('<p>Contact Form Submitted!</p>').prependTo('#mytestform');

     }
    );      
    jqxhr.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("There was an issue with your form" + " " + errorThrown); });       
});
```

Here is my html:

```
<div id = "dvdform"> <!-- begin of form -->
<form id="mytestform" name="mytestform" action="testme.php" method="post">
<fieldset>
<legend><strong>Contact Me</strong></legend>
<div id= "formsection">
<div><p> <label for="aname">Name:&nbsp;</label> <input name="aname" class="boxform" minlength=4 />
                   </p> </div>
<div><p><label for="email">E-mail</label> <input type="text" name="email"  maxlength="40"class="boxform" />
</p></div>
<div><p><label for="city">City</label> <input type="text" name="city"   class="boxform" maxlength="40" />
<br />
</p></div>
<div><p><label for="country">Company</label> <input type="text" name="country"  class="boxform" maxlength="40" />
<br />
</p></div>
<p><label for="country">Comments</label> <textarea name="req" class="required" cols="35" rows="30" style="height:100px;"> </textarea><br />
<br />
</p>

<div align="center" class="submitbox"> 
  <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT" style="width:175px; height:20px;"> 
</div>
</div> 
<!-- End of Form Section -->
</fieldset>
 </form> 
</div>

COMBINING IT using the submithandler still does not work:
$(function() {
   $("#mytestform" ).validate({
           rules: {
                   aname: {
                           required: true,
                           minlength: 4,
                           maxlength: 20
                   },
                   req: {
                           required: true,
                           minlength: 4                        
                                              },
                        email: {
                               required: true,
                               email: true
                       },                      
           },

           messages: {
                       email: "Enter a valid email address.",
             },

             submitHandler: function(form) {
                var jqxhr = $.post("testme.php", $("#mytestform").serialize());
        jqxhr.done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) { 
            //alert(textStatus + " second success " + data); 
            $('<p>Contact Form Submitted!</p>').prependTo('#mytestform');

         }
        );      
        jqxhr.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { alert("There was an issue with your form" + " " + errorThrown); });       
    });  
   });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code and the validation plugin both bind handlers for the `submit` event. I don't think there's any assurance that validation's handler will run first.

Instead, implement your AJAX call as the `submitHandler` option to the validation plugin. This ensures that it performs validation, and only runs the AJAX code when the validaiton is successful.

```
$(function () {
    $("#mytestform").validate({
        rules: {
            aname: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4,
                maxlength: 20
            },
            req: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 4
            },
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true
            }
        },

        messages: {
            email: "Enter a valid email address."
        },

        submitHandler: function (form) {
            var jqxhr = $.post("testme.php", $("#mytestform").serialize());
            jqxhr.done(function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                //alert(textStatus + " second success " + data); 
                $('<p>Contact Form Submitted!</p>').prependTo('#mytestform');

            });
            jqxhr.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert("There was an issue with your form" + " " + errorThrown);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/FPX8b/1/)

Comment: @JacklynN, you need a `return false` as the last line inside the `submitHandler` callback function to block the normal page redirect on submit.  See my answer for demo.

Comment: @Sparky The example in the documentation you linked to doesn't return false.

Comment: @Barmar, the documentation can be sketchy sometimes.  In addition to that, the developer has recently mentioned perhaps eliminating the need for the `return false` in the handler.  I leave it in my examples so the reader/user does not have to worry about the version.

Comment: @Barmar, yes, in the latest version of the plugin, it appears that the need for a `return false` is obsolete.  In any case, your answer is also correct and the OP's code should be working.

Comment: @Sparky FYI, I just checked 1.9.0 and it didn't require `return false` either.

Comment: @Barmar, good to know, but I never said I checked them all... just the latest.

Comment: @Sparky I know, it was just FYI. So unless you're using a very old version, it shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Also, same in version 1.6... I could have sworn I solved more than a few SO problems simply by adding the `return false`.  I need to pay special attention to this from now on.

Comment: Hello, it is still bypassing the validation. despite that. Please advise

Comment: You had syntax errors in your code; braces didn't match properly and there was an extra semicolon.  Didn't you see the error in the Javascript console (that should be the first place you look when a script isn't working as expected)? See the corrected code in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need an external `click` or `submit` handler with this plugin.  Everything is handled automatically.  You put the `ajax` inside the `submitHandler` callback function and the form is reliably validated before the `ajax` function is fired.  You also need a `return false` as the last line inside the `submitHandler` callback function to block the default page redirect on form submit.  *(for the later versions of the plugin, it appears that you do not need the `return false` because it's already built into the plugin when using the callback; it does not hurt anything to use it.)*

[As per documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions):

> **submitHandler**,  Callback, Default: default (native) form submit
>  Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is
>   valid. Gets the form as the only argument. Replaces the default
>   submit. **The right place to submit a form via Ajax** after it
>   validated.

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Sf5j2/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        // your rules and/or options,
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            // ajax goes here
            return false; // needed when using ajax
        }
    });

});
```